# How Do You Call OnVolumeDown In Other Functions?

Tags: java, android

I have:

```
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN || keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP) {
        // Do your thing
        TheTimer.cancel();
        TheTimer.start();
        return true;
    } else {
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

Right now I have a countDownTimer and I want to call `onKeyDown()` within it. I know that I want

```
onKeyDown(KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN, ?????)
```

What is it I put into the second argument?

Comment: It’s probably better to make another method and call it from both places.

Comment: Sorry, but how? Do you mean make a new onKeyDown or what?

Comment: If you want to trigger some code when no key is pressed, it makes no sense to make some arbitrary KeyEvent object because there isn’t a key event. Instead make a new method definining the action (I have no idea what it should be called) and call it from inside onKeyDown and also from somewhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your code in onKeyDown() into a another fuction. And it's not ideal to manually call fuctions like onKeyDown as they called automatically by the system when that events happens.

```
void keyDown() {
    TheTimer.cancel();
    TheTimer.start();
}
```

Then in the onKeyDown() and inside the countDownTimer call the keyDown() method.